# How to put cache with no expiration in redis using golang (beego)

Tags: caching, go, redis, beego

I have a problem doing my cache in redis.
I want to put data with no expiration. How can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
rediscache.Put("name",arrayString, 10 * time.Second)
```

Answer (score 0):

You may import "github.com/garyburd/redigo/redis"

AND do the following

```
var conn, _ = redis.Dial("tcp", "X.X.X.X:6379")

conn.Do("SET", "key", "value")
```